KMP Compose UI Play Video File
I have Kotlin multiplatform project and I want to play local video on the screen. My KMP project is Desktop only, so I don't have to worry about iOS and Android. Video is located locally at my PC, so it's not a online video. What is a proper way of doing it?
I saw some solutions using JavaFX, but I was unable to integrate it in my project properly.

The compose-multiplatform repo contains sample code for a video player:
https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/blob/master/experimental/components/VideoPlayer/library/src/desktopMain/kotlin/org/jetbrains/compose/videoplayer/DesktopVideoPlayer.kt
If you look at the code you can see it depends on vlcj, a java wrapper around the VLC media player.
